# Reading XML - How to deal with same tags - SAX

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing, sax, saxparser

I'm requesting the following XML file from a server:

```
<CreateAccount>
<Customer>ApiTest</Customer>
<CustomerLoginName>ApiTest</CustomerLoginName>
<Result>Success</Result>
<Reason>Country added</Reason>
<Result>Success</Result>
<Reason>Timezone added</Reason>
<Result>Success</Result>
<Reason>Request completely succeeded</Reason>
</CreateAccount>
```

I'm interested in the result of the request and the last reason. If an error appears, I'm receiving this XML:

```
<CreateAccount>
<Customer>ApiTest</Customer>
<Result>Failed</Result>
<Reason>Request completely or partially failed.</Reason>
</CreateAccount>
```

How do I handle the same tags? I was following these instructions: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement a [state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine).

You have 3 states: `Initial`, `Success` and `Failed`. You start at `Initial`, then wait until you receive the `Result` tag. You switch state according to the content of the `Result` tag - choosing either `Success` or `Failed`.

Then, when you're handling the same tag such as `Reason` you can handle it differently according to which state you're in.

If you're only interested in the last reason, keep saving the reason in a state variable. When you finish parsing, its value is going to be the last one.